# How to pass a "new" object in JavaScript in Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to pass objects from one client to another client, e.g. pieces in a multiplayer board game. I have a working solution using `JSON.parser` and `__proto__`, but I'm curious to know if there is a better way.

Client sends:

```
var my_piece = new BoardPiece();
// ... my_piece is assigned data, like x-y coordinates
socket.send(JSON.stringify(my_piece));
```

Server forwards the piece to others:

```
client.broadcast(piece);
```

Another client receives:

```
var your_piece = JSON.parse(json);
your_piece.__proto__ = BoardPiece.prototype; // provide access to BoardPiece's functions
```

It's the last step where I use `__proto__` that I'm concerned I may be shooting myself in the foot. Is there a better suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// clientone.js

var piece = new BoardPiece();
// ...
socket.send(JSON.stringify(piece));

// clienttwo.js
var piece = BoardPiece.Create(JSON.parse(json));
...

// BoardPiece.js
function BoardPiece() {

}

BoardPiece.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var data = {};
    data.foo = this.foo;
    ...
    return data;
};

BoardPiece.Create = function(data) {
    var piece = new BoardPiece();
    piece.foo = data.foo;
    ...
    return piece;
}
```

Firstly using the `toJSON` method on your objects allows `JSON.stringify` to immediatly convert your object to JSON. This is part of the JSON API. The JSON API will call the `toJSON` method if it exists and converts that object to JSON.

This basically allows you to serialize your object as and how you want.

The second part is adding a factory method as a property of your constructor which takes your serialized JSON data and creates a new boardpiece. It will then inject your serialized data into that boardpiece object.

So your serializing only the data you care about and then passing that data through a factory method. This is the best way to send custom objects from one client to another.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This all makes sense, and I can see how this way allows you to filter out the properties you want to send and receive. However, in my case, I want all the properties of the object. So if I understand you correctly, I should not implement toJSON and it will JSONify all my properties. That means I would only have duplicate code for Create to maintain if I change a property in BoardPiece.

Comment: @BrentDaugherty you can just jsonify the entire object then `for (var prop in obj) { ... }` loop over the object and copy every property over. The idea is that Your basically adding a second constructor which takes another object and makes a clone. It's a common construct in OO to have a clone based constructor. You could even deal with it as a paramater of the constructor function and only handle it there.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of object syncing projects for node that might make life easier. For starters, check out:

- [NowJS](http://nowjs.com/)
- [node-object-sync](https://github.com/jonashuckestein/node-object-sync)
- [Re-using Backbone.js Models on the server with Node.js and Socket.io to build real-time apps](http://andyet.net/blog/2011/feb/15/re-using-backbonejs-models-on-the-server-with-node/)

Comment: Having shared objects via a layer of abstraction can get very expensive if your not aware of how the abstraction works specifically.  Theres a big difference between 500 cycles to get a local property of an object and 250 million cycles to get a property of an object that exist across a network. Generally when understood and used well abstractions like `now` can make your live easy.

Comment: Thanks. These are some great links to libraries that I'll include as I understand them more and things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Have tou tried jQuery's $.extend() method? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it's not clear whether that would account for an object's prototype. Regardless, I don't want to use third-party libraries; It's for smartphone devices.